# How to make the "Search with Google" menu option open up in a new tab by default in Safari?

Tags: safari, search, shortcut-menu

I know I can <kbd>Command</kbd>-click it to achieve that. What I want is to change the default behavior from opening in the same tab to opening in a new tab.

Is there an extension or a hidden configuration for that?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this article Jonathan Rentzsch creates a new service because he wants "Search with Google" to work in Chrome (his default browser) but a side benefit of following his tutorial is that your search should open in a new tab.

If your default browser is Safari it should open your new tab there.

http://rentzsch.tumblr.com/post/5794765921/search-with-google-using-chrome

Warning: This is essentially a follow directions, cut-and-paste affair but it does involve seeing code. I'm unaware of a easy to install extension to accomplish this same task.

Comment: This worked fine. The newly created option appears on the bottom of the context menu though, I wish it appeared on the top.